# can I solve this with a loop and how?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a large ecological data set that includes deployment IDs that need fixing.

Camera traps were deployed over a ten year period and the location of the camera trap is recorded as the deployment ID. However, camera traps may have been deployed in the same location twice, at different times. In this case, the deployment ID has been recorded as the same but they need to be unique.

And to clarify: Only one camera trap can be deployed to a location at a time. But over a ten year period, some locations had multiple camera traps.

So my goal is to make them unique deployment IDs.

In my attempt: I know that camera traps were not deployed for longer than 3 months. So, using the DateTime, if more than 100 days have passed I can assume it is a redeployment and I want to assign it a unique deployment ID. So I created a column with DateDiff

```
for (i in 2:nrow(data)){
    if (data$deploymentID[i] == data$deploymentID[i-1]){
        data$DateDiff[i] <- as.Date(data$DateTime[i], format = '%Y%m%d') - as.Date(data$DateTime[i-1], format = '%Y%m%d')
    }
}
```

Then, I thought that if I order the data, first by deployment ID, then by DateTime...

```
data[order(data$deploymentID, data$DateTime), ]
```

I would be able to use a loop that runs through the dataframe and if DateDiff is > 100, all following lines where deployment ID is the same, create unique deploymentID.

However, I am struggling to create a working loop for this last section!

[image: I've attached a picture to show the structure of my data]

Many thanks

Comment: From the [r] tag information: "Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead." Help others help you with a [mcve]. Provide your data in a way that is easy for others to put into their R session, by [edit]ing your question to include the output of the R command `dput(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`. First group by the `ID` and arrange the dates. You can then calculate the date difference with the `lag` function. Afterwards, you calculate with `cumsum` how often the deployment differs by more than 100 days and use this to generate a unique ID:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("B1-2-41", 8), rep("B1-2-44", 8)),
                   date = c(rep(as.Date("2019-05-01"), 8),
                            rep(as.Date("2018-01-01"), 6),
                            as.Date("2018-05-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01")))
library(dplyr)

data_new <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = date - lag(date, default = first(date)),
         unique_ID = paste0(ID, "_", cumsum(date_diff > 100) + 1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(ID)

> data_new
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   ID      date       date_diff unique_ID
   <fct>   <date>     <drtn>    <chr>    
 1 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 2 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 3 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 4 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 5 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 6 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 7 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 8 B1-2-41 2019-05-01   0 days  B1-2-41_1
 9 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
10 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
11 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
12 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
13 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
14 B1-2-44 2018-01-01   0 days  B1-2-44_1
15 B1-2-44 2018-05-01 120 days  B1-2-44_2
16 B1-2-44 2018-10-01 153 days  B1-2-44_3
```

Comment: Thank you so much @starja ! That group_by function is going to come in handy.